# Retrieve Memcached values using Whalin memcached

Tags: java, memcached

I get values from `memcached` and try to convert List of class but I get class exception like this `java.lang.String` cannot be cast to `java.util.List` can anyone help? Topic is POJO class

Code

```
MemCachedClient mc = new MemCachedClient();
List<Topic> topicList = (List<Topic>) mc.get("topics");
```

Error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.List
```

In memcache the key "topics" contains List of Topic class only

My memcache add and get code are 

       `public void add(String key, Object value) {
        System.out.println("The Object Values are:"+value.getClass().getName());
        mcClient.set(key, value);
        }
         public Object get(String fqn) {
        System.out.println("Gets class Name:"+mcClient.get(fqn).getClass());
        return mcClient.get(fqn);
    }`

My result are 
`The Object Values are:java.util.LinkedList
Gets class Name:class java.lang.String`

At the time of adding into memcached it is in Linked List but i get the values from memcache it is in String i dont know why it is.

Can anyone help....???

Comment: Please show us the code that causes the Exception and the StackTrace. Please edit you post and add the information there

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `mc.get("topics")` is returning `List<String>` rather than `List<Topic>` as you were expecting. Can you double check what you stored in the cache.

Comment: yeah checked i'm stored `List<Topic>` only. I think the whalin Memcached client get method return as String Object  `Retrieve a key from the server, using a specific hash. If the data was compressed or serialized when compressed, it will automatically
be decompressed or serialized, as appropriate. (Inclusive or)

Non-serialized data will be returned as a string, so explicit conversion to
numeric types will be necessary, if desired
`